# Get empty result api firebase [FCM]

Tags: php, json, laravel, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I've saved some of my mobile registration_codes that are connected with my development environment of Firebase. Once I send a manual notification by the api I receive empty feedback from Firebase himself. After debugging I found that the notification has not been send. What's wrong with my call, because the call I make is the same in the examples and the registration_code is exactly the code what I receive from Flutter libary of Firebase.

code:

```
$response = Http::withToken(env('FCM_TOKEN'))->post(self::GLOBAL_URL, [
    'registration_ids' => $request->users,
    'data' => [
        'title' => $request->title,
        'message' => $request->message,
    ],
]);

return response()->json(["result" => $response]);
```

result:

```
{
"result": {
    "cookies": {},
    "transferStats": {}
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you should not use `env` directly, [because your `.env` file will not be used when the configuration is cached](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/configuration#configuration-caching). Instead, you should set this value in your `config/services.php` file:

```php
return [
  'firebase' => [
    'fcm_token' => env('FCM_TOKEN')
  ]
];
```

Second, your issue is that you are serializing the `Illuminate\Http\Client\Response` object instead of getting its value. To return the JSON result of your request, call `json()`:

```php
$response = Http::withToken(config('firebase.fcm_token'))->post(self::GLOBAL_URL, [
    'registration_ids' => $request->users,
    'data' => [
        'title' => $request->title,
        'message' => $request->message,
    ],
])->json(); // Notice the `json` call here


return response()->json(["result" => $response]);
```

If you inspect the `Illuminate\Http\Client\Response` object itself, you will see that it contains `cookies` and `transferStats` properties (specifically, they are on the [`PendingRequest`](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/fd7b1c95b3a330e3f05f06f4c4efd8ab2f413d3f/src/Illuminate/Http/Client/PendingRequest.php) object). That's why you are seeing this in your result.